# jquery and js doesn´t work on aspx page using a masterpage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have some problems with vb .net:

I have a masterpage  like this

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage2.master.vb" Inherits="MasterPage2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Mi site</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <menu>
     code..
   </menu>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Body" runat="server">        
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
   <footer>
     code..
   </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

and a page aspx like this

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default3.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default3" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage2.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Body"  runat="Server">  
  <div>
      hello
  </div>
</asp:Content>
```

the page doesn´t show errors, but only the styles works, the js and scripts are not working, only using the masterpage, without her works fine

what is wrong?, can you help me?

I tried  changing the sources like this, but didnt work

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveURL("~/js/jquery.js")%>'></script>
```

Comment: Open a debug/developer window in your browser and look at the network trace when you load the page. Do you get any 404's for your scripts ?

Comment: thanks, also I tried this and dont have 404´s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include your jquery script files in the **master page**.

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

     <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>    
</head>
```

Include jquery function files that you created, in the **content page** which you want to use.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">    

    <script src="js/superfish.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: thanks, but still doesn´t work, why the line ContentPlaceHolderID="head"   means for the head from the masterpage?